# GameDev: Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, requestanimationframe

Hi guys out there of my computer ;-)
I am trying to develope for myself a game with HTML 5 & JS & CSS. In many tutorials i saw the method "requestAnimationFrame". I copied and tried to recognize the mechanics of "requestAnimationFrame".

I show you some sourceCode(fullJSCode) and I hope you can understand what my problem is:
http://pastebin.com/YXf7Nkwd

My loop isnt working...i bind keys on ("W","A","S","D") to move an rectangle square...but my square isnt moving :(

Can anyone help me please?

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Line 70, in the `update` method, you should use `this.speed` rather than just `speed` I think. Using just `speed` is trying to reference a local/global variable while `this.speed` will reference the `speed` variable on the `this` object which in this context is `entities`. Hope that helps!

Comment: I've just seen the OP's JS code and tried to respond to that. dunno where HTML is.